# Injecting angular1 service in angular2 directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular, babeljs

I'm reading lots of articles on this matter like [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html), [and this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#projecting-angular-1-content-into-angular-2-components) and [also this](http://ngcourse.rangle.io/handout/migrate/ng-upgrade/injecting_across_frameworks.html) but each one of these articles starts from a situation in which the NG1 service is a `class` and can be exported.

I'm in a very different situation, i often have multiple services in the same file and they are defined in a very old style manner like

```
angular.module('App.services').factory('SessionService',
    function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        [...]
    }
);
```

No `class`, no `export`.

And this stuff is directly linked in the page with an old fashioned `<script src="...">`

At the same time i'm trying to create new directives in Angular2 and these directives need those old fashioned services.

I get i should be able to write something like this

```
import {Injector,Component, Directive, ElementRef, Input, View} from 'angular2/core';

var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
    SessionService
]);

var SessionService = injector.get(SessionService);


@Component({
    selector: 'nav-bar'
})

@View({
    templateUrl: '/app/components/navbar/navBar.html'
})

export class navBar {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

but of course `SessionService` object is not found.

How can i get out of this mess?

[Additional Info]

Using `babel` as transpiler

`angular2-annotations` plugin added

A great article to understand the difference between Annotations and Decorators in angular2: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html

Comment: instead of trying to import script and manually inject ,try including all the scripts in you index.html in sequence.
Then you can directly import a service inside your controller by it name....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to leverage `@Inject`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nav-bar'
  templateUrl: '/app/components/navbar/navBar.html'
})
export class navBar {
  constructor(private @Inject('SessionService') sessionService) {

  }
}
```

See this plunkr for more details: http://plnkr.co/edit/U6ygjUUQ04mTGAAaC1pZ?p=preview

You can notice that with factory you can't use classes. It's only possible with services...

If you use ES6 only, you could try this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nav-bar'
  templateUrl: '/app/components/navbar/navBar.html'
})
export class navBar {
  constructor(sessionService) {

  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[ new Inject('...'), new Inject('...') ]];
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use @inject but i get `Unexpected token` on that. Yes i imported Inject from angular/core. And other notations like `@Component` works fine w/o errors... (using babel)

Comment: Do you bootstrap your application using the `bootstrap` method of the `UpgradeAdapter` class? See my plunkr. Otherwise the corresponding providers won't be there...

Comment: Yes of course. I can tell you @Inject for my transpiler is only valid if it's the first statement in a line... no idea why but basically i cannot use it inside a constructor or assign it to a variable...

Comment: Oh it seems that you use ES6 and not TypeScript. I think that the réagir of your problem. Decorators aren't at constructor parameter level. You could try to create a static get for the parameters property: static get parameters() { return [[ Inject('...'), Inject('...') ]]; }

Comment: Thank you, i actually wasn't realizing that i was only using ES6 and not TS,  in the end your solution actually worked, you just have to fix it by adding the `new` keyword before every `Inject`.